# LINQ Query using UDF that receives parameters from the query

Tags: linq, parameter-passing, user-defined-functions

I need help using a UDF in a LINQ which calculates a users position from a fixed point.

```
int pointX = 567, int pointY = 534; // random points on a square grid
var q = from n in _context.Users 
join m in _context.GetUserDistance(n.posY, n.posY, pointX, pointY, n.UserId) on n.UserId equals m.UserId
select new User() {
  PosX = n.PosX,
  PosY = n.PosY,
  Distance = m.Distance,        
  Name = n.Name,
  UserId = n.UserId
};
```

The GetUserDistance is just a UDF that returns a single row in a TVP with that users distance from the points deisgnated in pointX and pointY variables, and the designer generates the following for it:

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.FunctionAttribute(Name="dbo.GetUserDistance", IsComposable=true)]
public IQueryable<GetUserDistanceResult> GetUserDistance([global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(Name="X1", DbType="Int")] System.Nullable<int> x1, [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(Name="X2", DbType="Int")] System.Nullable<int> x2, [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(Name="Y1", DbType="Int")] System.Nullable<int> y1, [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(Name="Y2", DbType="Int")] System.Nullable<int> y2, [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(Name="UserId", DbType="Int")] System.Nullable<int> userId)
{
    return this.CreateMethodCallQuery<GetUserDistanceResult>(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), x1, x2, y1, y2, userId);
}
```

when i try to compile i get

```
The name 'n' does not exist in the current context
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't really a UDF problem - it's a LINQ problem. You can't use an existing range variable in the source part of a `join` clause, so this would be equally wrong:

```
string[] files = ...;
var query = from file in files
            join line in File.ReadAllLines(file) on file equals line
            ...
```

I suspect you'll need to write it as multiple `from` clauses instead:

```
var q = from n in _context.Users 
        from m in _context.GetUserDistance(n.posY, n.posY, pointX, pointY, n.UserId)
        where n.UserId == m.UserId
        ...
```

Although it seems slightly odd to need a join at all, when I'd *expect* the results of `GetUserDistance` to only be for that user anyway, right? This might be clearer with:

```
var q = from n in _context.Users 
        let m = _context.GetUserDistance(n.posY, n.posY, pointX, pointY, n.UserId)
                        .Single()
        ...
```

Comment: Jon the second answer worked perfectly, using the "let" clause - i tried that unsuccessfully but without the .Single(). Thank you very much. @Wasp - this is identical to your answer but i have to tick Jons repsonse because it was first and provided a couple of scnearios to try, but thanks to you both

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need a join, try this:

```
int pointX = 567, int pointY = 534; // random points on a square grid
var q = from n in _context.Users 
let m = _context.GetUserDistance(n.posY, n.posY, pointX, pointY, n.UserId).Single()
select new User() {
    PosX = n.PosX,
    PosY = n.PosY,
    Distance = m.Distance,        
    Name = n.Name,
    UserId = n.UserId
};
```

Comment: Of course Jon was faster, and made me spot something I missed, fixed.